# UILabel is growing only after orientation

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have uilabel with number of lines 0 and set programatic constrains for 4 edges pin to superview. when I run I see the label is not showing multilines, but after I orient the device for first time then it is started showing the multi lines, any help?

```
private let headerLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

    let leading = headerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor)
    let top = headerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor)
   let trailing = headerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
    let bottom = headerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leading, top, trailing, bottom])
```

Comment: Sounds wierd. You have any code for how you set up the label?

Comment: added in the question

Comment: Your constraints are not activated... you have to call `leading.activate = true`

Comment: No I added the constraints as well   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leading, top, trailing, bottom])

Comment: Also, you put constraints on `headerLabel` while you label name is `lbl` it's really confusing when you show parts of code. Also it's maybe problems with your superView.. that it isn't big enough. Might want to open viewHiearchy and check heights?

Answer (score 0):

- Pin the label to be horizontally and vertically in the middle of the superview.
- Add leading trailing top-bottom constraints to be greater than equal to 10
- set number of lines to 0
- You may even make the label scroll when the text is big enough.

Comment: Its not the solution

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving 50 topAnchor more. So, you can see label below status bar.

```
private let lbl: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    lbl.text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. "
    view.addSubview(lbl)

    let leading = lbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
    let top = lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50)
    let trailing = lbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
    let bottom = lbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)

    let constraintArray = [leading,top,trailing,bottom]

    for item in constraintArray {
        item.isActive = true
    }
}
```